# Issue with URI when deploying Grails on Heroku

Tags: grails, deployment, heroku

I try to deploy a Grails application on Heroku for the first time. On our local server (Tomcat) the war file can be deployed and the app used without any problem. For example the source contains a login form which points to the LoginController (`url="[controller: 'login', action:'login']"`).

When we deploy the war file to Heroku (runned by Tomcat) then the app doesn't work. When running "heroku logs" we get the following error:

```
2013-04-17T11:48:20.081459+00:00 app[web.1]: 2013-04-17 11:48:20,081 [http-nio-27162-exec-9] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - UnknownControllerException occurred when processing request: [POST] /login/login
2013-04-17T11:48:20.081459+00:00 app[web.1]:    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:195)
2013-04-17T11:48:20.081459+00:00 app[web.1]:    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)
2013-04-17T11:48:20.081459+00:00 app[web.1]: No controller found for URI [//grails/login/login]!. Stacktrace follows:
2013-04-17T11:48:20.081459+00:00 app[web.1]: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.exceptions.UnknownControllerException: No controller found for URI [//grails/login/login]!
```

As it looks like, Heroku automatically adds `//grails` in the URI. My question is where this comes from? Obviously it can't find the controller within this URI as `//grails` is not valid at all in our code.

Any ideas?

Comment: You have grails.serverURL configured?

Comment: Tried with and without and there was no difference.